# Authentication against Azure AD, authorization in AWS

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, saml-2.0, amazon-iam, azure-active-directory

Entering the AWS management console, how does one build an SSO solution where authentication is done against Azure AD but authorization level is in AWS IAM?

Azure AD SAML claim will not include any security group data, since we don't want to overload SAML token with metadata. Same applies to Kerberos tickets. Hence using the Azure AD Graph API is out of question as well.

Basically the SAML assertion will only include data about authenticated user.

The AssumeRoleWithSAML API is *role*-driven, whereas we would need a SAML based solution that is *user*-driven (mapping incoming user data with IAM user). Any help is welcome.